# How to change partial substrings to mixed case in Perl

Tags: perl, rename, partial, utility, lowercase

The Perl rename utility does a great job in everyday file work, especially in private when I check my MP3 collection now and then.

Some folks have a *terrible* habit of always capitalizing the artist name, like this

```
03 - ARTIST NAME - Song Title.mp3
```

I'd like this to be renamed to a more calmly-looking mixed case, like this

```
03 - Artist Name - Song Title.mp3
```

However, it should be done in an intelligent way, too.

There might be French or Italian titles like:

```
05 - JEAN BAGUETTE - Honi soit qui mal y pense.mp3
```

or

```
07 - SIGNORE AL FORNO - Pazzi sono tutti i calciatori.mp3
```

And hence, I do *not* want these to get changed to mixed case after the `-`, only the artist part.

One approach, which did not work, was

```
rename 's/(\d{1,2} - )([A-Z ]+)([\s\S]+)/$1lc($2)$3/' filename
```

I'm posting it anyway, because it always gives you a better clue what I'm trying to do.

I've also tried replacing the `$2` with a temporary variable (since I am not allowed to change $2 as it's read-only) and do the `lc()` before printing out the result, but I did not succeed. But I'm quite a Perl beginner, anyhow.

Comment: So you want to change everything between the first pair of hyphens to mixed case?

Answer (score 3):

The clearest way I know to do this is to do a two-stage evaluated (using the `/e` modifier) substitution.

In the code below, the outer substitution selects the artist name including its bounding hyphens and substitutes it.

The inner one takes `$1` - the artist name - and substitutes every subsequence of non-space characters with the same string first lower-cased with `lc` and then capitalised with `ucfirst`.

As it stands the program will print the before and after names. Remove the `#` from the rename line to do a rename.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = (
  '05 - JEAN BAGUETTE - Honi soit qui mal y pense.mp3',
  '07 - SIGNORE AL FORNO - Pazzi sono tutti i calciatori.mp3',
);

for my $file (@data) {

  (my $new = $file) =~ s{(-[^-]+-)}{
    (my $artist = $1) =~ s/(\S+)/ucfirst lc $1/eg;
    $artist;
  }e;

  print "$file\n";
  print "$new\n";
  print "\n";
  # rename $file, $new;
}
```

**output**

```
05 - JEAN BAGUETTE - Honi soit qui mal y pense.mp3
05 - Jean Baguette - Honi soit qui mal y pense.mp3

07 - SIGNORE AL FORNO - Pazzi sono tutti i calciatori.mp3
07 - Signore Al Forno - Pazzi sono tutti i calciatori.mp3
```

---

**Update**

Another way you might like is to split the file name on the hyphens, edit the second part and join them back together.

The main loop from above becomes

```
for my $file (@data) {

  my @file = split /-/, $file;
  $file[1] =~ s/(\S+)/ucfirst lc $1/eg;
  my $new = join '-', @file;

  print "$file\n";
  print "$new\n";
  print "\n";
  # rename $file, $new;
}
```

and the functionality and output are unchanged.

---

**Update 2**

> I just experimented with using /-.*?-/ then using substr($_, $-[0],
>   $+[0]) as an lvalue for =~ s/// but sadly it didn't work

That seemed like such a neat idea I had to experiment with it.

Your call to `substr` is wrong, as `$-[0]` and `$+[0]` are offsets into the string. The third parameter to `substr` must be a string *length* so you need to write `substr($_, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0])`

This code works fine, and again produces the same results as before

```
for my $file (@data) {

  next unless $file =~ /-[^-]+-/;
  my $new = $file;
  substr($new, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0]) =~ s/(\S+)/ucfirst lc $1/eg;

  print "$file\n";
  print "$new\n";
  print "\n";
  # rename $file, $new;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this might be the best way.  I just experimented with using `/-.*?-/` then using `substr($_, $-[0], $+[0])` as an lvalue for `=~ s///` but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: @ephemient: thank you for an excellent idea! I have updated my answer again with it working correctly. A new idiom for Perl.

Comment: No need to do `/e` when we have `\u` and `\L` in the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks a HUGE bunch for your efforts! Well, if I had needed a whole program-like script, I would've written some myself, but I felt this must be feasible in a much neater way. Just as the above one. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the escape sequences for `ucfirst` (`\u`) and `lc` (`\L`) in your regex, combined with a look-ahead assertion that requires a dash further ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w)(\w+)(?=.*-)/\u$1\L$2/g'
```

If you want to be more correct, you can use `\pL` (letters) instead of `\w`. I assume this will work with the `rename` tool.

**ETA:** Updated to use `\u` instead of `\U`.

Comment: You want `\u` for the first one, not `\U`.

Comment: @tchrist Actually, since `$1` is just one letter, it doesn't really matter. But I suppose it could be simplified to `s/(\w+)(?=.*-)/\u\L$1/g`.

Comment: No, that’s not true.  Uppercase and titlecase are *not* the same casemap for all possible codepoints. Similarly, it’s actually formally incorrect to first map to to lc and then to either tc or uc. You have to write `\u$1\L$2`, not `\u\L$2`. Yes, there are only six code points where it matters: U+0130, U+03F4, U+1E9E, U+2126, U+212A, and U+212B.

Comment: You've just gotten an extra +1 for this warning. It's really a diabolic pitfall, prone to get beginners get trapped into.